# Laravel - How to make a button that adds column to database table

Tags: database, laravel, web-applications

I want to make a flexible database for my web application. how can I make a button on my web application administration interface that enables me to create a new column on my database table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic tables is a bad idea, but if you really want it, you can [create Artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#writing-commands) which will create migration from a stub and run `php artisan migrate` command for you.

Then just [call this command from your code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#calling-commands-via-code).